# Check if( selected() )

Tags: theme-development, theme-options

I have been working on adding options to a theme I am making. I have run into trouble having multiple options in a select box. I am looking to `echo` a code, depending on what value is saved in the option field.

OPTIONS

```
function nikon_woocommerce_shop_width() {
    $shop_width = esc_attr( get_option( 'nikon_woocommerce_shop_width' ) );
    ?>

    <select name="nikon_woocommerce_shop_width" value="<?php $nikon_woocommerce_shop_width; ?>">
        <option value="1" <?php selected( $shop_width, 1 ); ?> >1/4</option>
        <option value="2" <?php selected( $shop_width, 2 ); ?> >1/3</option>
        <option value="3" <?php selected( $shop_width, 3 ); ?> >1/2</option>
        <option value="4" <?php selected( $shop_width, 4 ); ?> >Full</option>
    </select>

    <?php
}
```

FUNCTIONS

```
$woocomemrce_shop_width = esc_attr( get_option( 'nikon_woocomemrce_shop_width' ) );

function nikon_woocommerce_shop_width_preoutput() {

    if( selected( 1, $woocommerce_shop_width, false ) ) {
        echo 'class="col-3';
    } else if( selected( 2, $woocommerce_shop_width, false ) ) {
        echo 'class="col-4';
    } else if( selected( 3, $woocommerce_shop_width, false ) ) {
        echo 'class="col-6';
    } else if( selected( 4, $woocommerce_shop_width, false ) ) {
        echo 'class="col-12';
    }

}
add_action( 'nikon_woocommerce_shop_width_output', 'nikon_woocommerce_shop_width_preoutput' );
```

FRONTEND HTML

```
<?php

$woocommerce_shop_class = esc_attr( get_option( 'nikon_woocommerce_shop_class' ) );
$woocomemrce_shop_width = esc_attr( get_option( 'nikon_woocommerce_shop_width' ) );

?>

<div id="woocommerce_shop">

    <?php if( selected( 2, $woocommerce_shop_class, false) ) { echo ''; } else { echo '<div class="container">'; }  ?>

        <div class="row">

            <div <?php echo $woocomemrce_shop_width; ?> <?php do_action( 'nikon_woocommerce_shop_width_output' ); ?> >

                <?php woocommerce_content(); ?>

            </div>

            <div class="col">

                <?php get_sidebar( 'woocommerce' ); ?>

            </div>

        </div>

    <?php if( selected( 2, $woocommerce_shop_class, false) ) { echo ''; } else { echo '</div>'; }   ?>

</div>
```

I can `echo` just the option and it will show the related number to the saved option, however I cannot seem to work out how to make the `if` statement work.

If you need further details, please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`selected` is just an equals if statement that outputs `selected` or not. It doesn't perform any special checks, it just makes the code for `<option>` tags a bit nicer. Without the `selected` function, you'd need to use a ternary operator, or temporary variables, the code for outputting forms would be awful.

As the official docs say:

> Outputs the html selected attribute.
>
> #### Description
>
> Compares the first two arguments and if identical marks as selected
>
> https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/selected/

So just compare the first two arguments.

What you tried to do here:

```php
} else if( selected( 3, $woocommerce_shop_width, false ) ) {
```

Is just a very complicated and broken way of doing this:

```php
} else if( 3 == $woocommerce_shop_width ) {
```

Comment: I thought there was an easier way! Still getting the hang of this PHP stuff lol